# What does "in-flight request" mean for a web browser?

Tags: performance, http

I'm trying to decipher the meaning of "in-flight request" in the [context](https://github.com/WPO-Foundation/webpagetest/blob/master/docs/Metrics/TimeToInteractive.md) of a browser loading a web page:

> Look for the first interactive window where there is a contiguous period of 5 seconds fully contained within the interactive window with no more than **2 in-flight requests**

Is it referring to HTTP requests? If so, what's the difference between an in-flight request and any other kind of request?

Comment: The document you link says: "At any point in time this is the number of outstanding requests."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An in-flight request is a request that has been started but not yet completed, a.k.a. a request in progress.